# Most concise way to initialize a C# hashtable

Tags: c#, hashtable

Does C# allow hashtables to be populated in one-line expressions? I am thinking of something equivalent to the below Python:

```
mydict = {"a": 23, "b": 45, "c": 67, "d": 89}
```

In other words, is there an alternative to setting each key-value pair in a separate expression?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

C# 3 has a language extension called *collection initializers* which allow you to initialize the values of a collection in one statement.

Here is an example using a `Dictionary<,>`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>
        {
            {"a", 23}, {"b", 45}, {"c", 67}, {"d", 89}
        };
    }
}
```

This language extension is supported by the C# 3 compiler and any type that implements `IEnumerable` and has a public `Add` method.

If you are interested I would suggest you read [this question I asked here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459652/why-do-c-collection-initializers-work-this-way) as to *why* the C# team implemented this language extension in such a curious manner (once you read the excellent answers to the question you will see that it makes a lot of sense).

Comment: Is there a similar syntax for defining dictionaries that are multiple levels deep? For example, `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,decimal>>`?

Comment: I found the technique and will add it as an edit to your answer, although it's a bit wordy, not sure if it's saving anyone much time.