# Why does a collection initializer expression require IEnumerable to be implemented?

Tags: c#, syntax, language-design

Why does this generate a compiler error:

```
class X { public void Add(string str) { Console.WriteLine(str); } }

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // error CS1922: Cannot initialize type 'X' with a collection initializer
        // because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'
        var x = new X { "string" };
    }
}
```

but this doesn’t:

```
class X : IEnumerable
{
    public void Add(string str) { Console.WriteLine(str); }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        // Try to blow up horribly!
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // prints “string” and doesn’t throw
        var x = new X { "string" };
    }
}
```

What is the reason for restricting collection initializers — which are syntactic sugar for a call to an `Add` method — to classes that implement an interface which doesn’t *have* an `Add` method and which isn’t used?

Comment: There are some things in C# I just dont get. This is one of them. Another is `foreach`.

Comment: @leppie: What don't you "get" about foreach?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I think leppie refers to the fact that the compiler simply requires the presence of a method without requiring a specific interface which is sort of duck-typing behaviour in a strongly-typed language.

Comment: @0xA3: That's mostly explained by the lack of generics in C# 1. This duck typing allowed for strongly typed iterators using value types without boxing. I *suspect* it wouldn't be present in C# if it had generics to start with, although it's still used to avoid boxing the iterator when you use foreach over a `List<T>`, for example.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: The fact that it does more than one expects. I do 'get' it, I just dont get why. But as you said, it could be to do with generics.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459652/why-do-c-sharp-collection-initializers-work-this-way

Answer (score 29, accepted):

An *object* initializer doesn't; a *collection* initializer does. It's so that it's applied to classes which really represent collections, rather than just arbitrary ones which have an `Add` method. I have to admit that every so often I've "implemented" `IEnumerable` explicitly, just to allow collection initializers - but thrown a `NotImplementedException` from `GetEnumerator()`.

Note that early in C# 3's development, collection initializers had to implement `ICollection<T>`, but that was found to be too restrictive. Mads Torgersen [blogged about this change](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madst/archive/2006/10/10/what-is-a-collection_3f00_.aspx), and the reason behind requiring `IEnumerable`, back in 2006.

Comment: Wouldn’t the same argument apply to the LINQ query syntax? Yet it doesn’t require any interfaces, and even allows the “iterator variable” to be a type name and “Where/Select” to be a static method...

Comment: @Timwi: Sort of, although it's less likely that a query expression will actually compile against an arbitrary type than a collection initializer - I suspect that `Add` has more "other meanings" than `Where` and `Select` methods with appropriate parameter types. Also note that there *isn't* one appropriate interface which could have been applied to sanity-check LINQ queries - think about Reactive Extnesions, which doesn't have any common interface with LINQ to Objects...

Comment: Not a day goes by without me wishing .NET 2 was the first version... 90% of all the cruft in .NET seems to come from the existence of .NET 1 with its non-generic stuff...