# Access to list<T> values

Tags: c#, list

I am a beginner with coding and trying to solve simple problem:

I have list with three columns and trying to access values stored in the list. And it gives me no answer... any idea? thanks

```
private void btnImage1Load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = openFileDialog1.FileName;                    
    }

    public class ListThreeColumns
    {
        public int XCoord { get; set; }
        public int YCoord { get; set; }
        public Color Color { get; set; }
    }

    private List<ListThreeColumns> GetPixels()
    {
        Bitmap picture = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);

        List<ListThreeColumns> colorList = new List<ListThreeColumns>
        {

        };

        for (int y = 0; y < picture.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < picture.Width; x++)
            {
                colorList.Add(new ListThreeColumns { XCoord = x, YCoord = y, Color = picture.GetPixel(x, y) });
            }
        }
        return colorList;
    }


    private void btnScanPixels_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<ListThreeColumns> seznamBarev = GetPixels();
       MessageBox.Show(seznamBarev[6].ToString());


    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a collection initializer expression require IEnumerable to be implemented?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3716626/299327)

Answer (score 4):

In this line:

```
MessageBox.Show(seznamBarev[6].ToString());
```

... you're accessing element 6 of the list, but then just calling `ToString` on it. As you haven't overridden `ListThreeElements` (which would be better named `Pixel`, by the way) that means the result won't be particularly useful.

You could write:

```
ListThreeColumns pixel = seznamBarev[6];
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}, {1} - {2}", pixel.X, pixel.Y, pixel.Color);
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do?
If you want to show each item in string you can use Jon way.
But it's better to move operations to your class.
If you override 'ToString()' method in ListThreeColumns class, your code works correctly, without change.

```
 public class ListThreeColumns
{
    public int XCoord { get; set; }
    public int YCoord { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }

    public override ToString()
    {
         return string.Format("X={0}, Y={1}, Color=({2};{3};{4})", 
             this.XCoord , this.YCoord , Color.R,Color.G,Color.B );
    }
}
```