# Use collection initializer for BiDirection dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, ienumerable, bidirectional

About BiDirection dictionary: [Bidirectional 1 to 1 Dictionary in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268321/bidirectional-1-to-1-dictionary-in-c-sharp)

My bi-dictionary is:

```
    internal class BiDirectionContainer<T1, T2>
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<T1, T2> _forward = new Dictionary<T1, T2>();
        private readonly Dictionary<T2, T1> _reverse = new Dictionary<T2, T1>();

        internal T2 this[T1 key] => _forward[key];

        internal T1 this[T2 key] => _reverse[key];

        internal void Add(T1 element1, T2 element2)
        {
            _forward.Add(element1, element2);
            _reverse.Add(element2, element1);
        }
    }
```

I want to add elements like this:

```
BiDirectionContainer<string, int> container = new BiDirectionContainer<string, int>
{
    {"111", 1},
    {"222", 2},
    {"333", 3},    
}
```

But im not sure if it right to use `IEnumerable` in `BiDirectionContainer`?
What should i return if so? Is there any other way to implement such functionality?

Comment: @Dirk Vollmar all i need is simple initialization. I not plan to use it in foreach statments. But i afraid that my class can confuse other people who can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest is probably to enumerate the elements of the forward (or backward, whatever seems more natural) dictionary like so:

```
internal class BiDirectionContainer<T1, T2> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T1, T2>>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<T1, T2> _forward = new Dictionary<T1, T2>();
    private readonly Dictionary<T2, T1> _reverse = new Dictionary<T2, T1>();

    internal T2 this[T1 key] => _forward[key];

    internal T1 this[T2 key] => _reverse[key];

    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<T1, T2>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T1, T2>>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _forward.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _forward.GetEnumerator();
    }

    internal void Add(T1 element1, T2 element2)
    {
        _forward.Add(element1, element2);
        _reverse.Add(element2, element1);
    }
}
```

As an aside: If you only want to be able to use collection initializer, it is required by the C# language specification that your class implements `System.Collections.IEnumerable` *and* also provides an `Add` method that is applicable for each element initializer (i.e. basically number and type of arguments must match). The interface is required by the compiler, but the `GetEnumerator` method is not called when the collection is initialized (only the add method is). It is required because the collection initializer should only be available for things that actually are a collection and not just something that has an add method. [Therefore it is fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3716652/40347) to just add the interface without actually implementing a method body (`public IEnumerator GetEnumerator(){ throw new NotImplementedException(); }`)