# What C# feature allows the use of an "object literal" type notation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, routevalues

I'm coming from JavaScript, and I know that `{ }` is an object literal, not needing to require the `new Object` call; I'm wondering if it's the same with C# in the `{"id",id}, {"saveChangesError",true}` part.

I know there are two C# features in here, care to explain to me more about what they are?

```
new RouteValueDictionary()
{ //<------------------------------[A: what C#  feature is this?] -------||
   {"id",id}, //<------------------[B: what C# feature is this also?]    ||
   {"saveChangesError",true}                                             ||
}); //<------------------------------------------------------------------||
```

Comment: It is just special magic in C# to automatically call some methods (`Add` in particular) *after* the object has been created.

Comment: For the answerees: can *property initialization* be mixed with *collection initialization*? (This should be present in explaining the "outer" construct, as it could have been: `new Foo { Bar = Quz }`.)

Comment: @pst: No, not even in VB.NET, oddly enough...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459652/why-do-c-sharp-collection-initializers-work-this-way (talks about Add)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a single feature - [*collection initializers*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx). Like object initializers, it can only be used as part of an object initialization expression, but basically it calls `Add` with whatever arguments are present - using braces to specify multiple arguments, or single arguments at a time without the extra braces, e.g.

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
```

See section 7.6.10.3 of the C# 4 spec for more information.

Note that the compiler requires two things of a type for it to be used for collection initializers:

- It must implement `IEnumerable`, although the compiler doesn't generate any calls to `GetEnumerator`
- It must have appropriate overloads for an `Add` method

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class Test : IEnumerable
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var t = new Test
        {
            "hello",
            { 5, 10 },
            { "whoops", 10, 20 }
        };
    }

    public void Add(string x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Add({0})", x);
    }

    public void Add(int x, int y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Add({0}, {1})", x, y);
    }

    public void Add(string a, int x, int y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Add({0}, {1}, {2})", a, x, y);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()        
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's have a link to MSDN documentation in the answer, at least. :)

Comment: @DanJ: Yeah, I'm getting there :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Applying the principles of Agile to answering StackOverflow questions, eh? Hmm. ;)

Answer (score 7):

That's collection initialization syntax. This:

```
RouteValueDictionary d = new RouteValueDictionary()
{                             //<-- A: what C#  feature is this?
   {"id",id},                 //<-- B: what C# feature is this also?    
   {"saveChangesError",true}
});
```

is basically equivalent to this:

```
RouteValueDictionary d = new RouteValueDictionary();
d.Add("id", id);
d.Add("saveChangesError", true);
```

The compiler recognizes the fact that it implements `IEnumerable` and has an appropriate `Add` method and uses that.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx

Comment: "dictionary initialization syntax" makes it sound like C# *as a language* has built-in knowledge of dictionaries. It doesn't. It'll work with *any* type which implements `IEnumerable` and has appropriate `Add` methods.

Comment: @JonSkeet: How does it recognize the fact that it's a `KeyValuePair`?

Comment: @minitech: It doesn't. It recognizes the fact that there's an `Add(key, value)` method. See my answer for an example of this. Also note that in reality, the variable is only assigned *after* the `Add` calls - it's as if you've got a temporary variable before that.

Comment: Allow me to write in this comment :) (@edit: That's why I said "basically")

Comment: @phoog: Jon Skeet beat you to it, because Jon Skeet beats everyone to it ;)

Comment: Yeah, Jon Skeet apparently doesn't have the problem that I have of writing a 4-paragraph comment and then deciding to delete the last 3 paragraphs as superfluous.

Answer (score 4):

Please look at [Anonymous Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types)
They allow you to do something like this:

```
var v = new { Amount = 108, Message = "Hello" };
```