# unusual C# syntax

Tags: c#, syntax

I have some C# code which I don't understand:

```
        CliRootCommand _outerCommand = new CliRootCommand
        {
            new CliCommand("inner")
            {
                new CliOption<string>("--optionOne"),
                new CliOption<string>("--optionTwo")
            }
        };
```

1. Does

   ```
   CliRootCommand _outerCommand = new CliRootCommand
   ```

   instantiate a new instance of `CliRootCommand`? If yes, why does it not require the `()` at the end (note that it works in the exact same way even if I add the `()` to it) ?
2. What does the stuff in the `{ }` after the first line do? If it was inside the missing `()` then it would be passing an object as the argument for the constructor for `CliRootCommand` but this is not the case

Comment: It's a collection initialization thing. CliRootCommand is a collection and CliCommand is an item. You can omit () when you are using object or collection initialization syntax. The default constructor will be called.

Comment: You can see 4 keyword "new" objects in your example. The parent (or root) object is CliRootCommand. Inside of the root, it is creating another object CliCommand, which has two children objects, respectively, inside of that (CliOption). The brackets are for instantiating an object, for setting it's properties. For example: var _event = new Event { Year = 2023 }; class Event { public int Year { get; set; } }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Syntactic sugar for adding items to collections in object initialisers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983400/syntactic-sugar-for-adding-items-to-collections-in-object-initialisers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s a lot to unpack here.

- Both CliRootCommand and CliCommand support [collection initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers)
- When you use initializers you can omit the brackets of the constructor if there is a default / parameterless constructor available.

Answer (score 5):

This is a [**collection initializer**:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers)

> Collection initializers let you specify one or more element initializers when you initialize a collection type that implements IEnumerable and has Add with the appropriate signature as an instance method or an extension method.

The "extension method" part is kind of cool, because it means you can monkeypatch this onto existing IEnumerable types to do "fun" things if you want.

This has been in C# since at least 2013, so 10 years now.